# Why can't Z3 propose a sort with no elements?

Tags: z3

Using Z3Py, I tried to build a program which Z3 would decide means that the sort `Human` is empty.

```
from z3 import *
from z3_helper import Z3Helper

Human = DeclareSort("Human")
is_mortal = Function("is_mortal", Human, BoolSort())
h = Const('h', Human)

s = Solver()
s.add([
    ForAll([h], And(is_mortal(h), Not(is_mortal(h))))
])

print s.check()
s.model()
```

But instead of returning a model where `Human` is empty, it returns `unsat`. Why is this?

If I remove the "all men are mortal" axiom, it returns an empty set as the model.

Is the problem that the existence of const `h` means that the existence of at least one `Human` is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMT-LIB and Z3 take the view that simply typed first-order logic assumes that all sorts are non-empty. See also http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-draft-3.pdf, section 5.1 onwards.